# Weird Artifacts around edges when converting PNG TO JPEG using PILLOW

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I was writing a basic utility for image conversions and whenever I convert PNG Images having a transparent background to JPEG there are some weird artifacts around the objects edges....I tried to find a solution for this in the documentation but was unable to find a solution that works for me.

[image]
[image]

This is the complete code and the function that deals with the image is "image_conversion"

```
"""

This moduel is used for image conversion.
----------------------------------------------

1. JPEG to PNG
2. PNG to JPEG
3. BMP to GIF
4. TIFF to JPEG
5. GIF to PNG
6. PSD to PNG
7. SVG to PNG 
8. RAW to JPEG
9. ICO to PNG or JPEG
10. WebP to PNG or JPEG


Input & Output Through :
----------------------------------------------

1. GUI [tkinter] 
2. Direct Input Through Command Line [sys.argv]


Input & Output Methods for both bulk and single file inputs :
----------------------------------------------

1. Standard Input to Standard Output
2. Specified Input to Standard Output
3. Standard Input to Specified Output
4. Specified Input to Specified Output

"""

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
from PIL import Image,ImageMath
import cairosvg


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()


def file_type():
    global user_input

    try:
        user_input = int(input("""

[1]  JPEG to PNG

[2]  PNG to JPEG

[3]  BMP to GIF

[4]  TIFF to JPEG

[5]  GIF to PNG

[6]  PSD to PNG

[7]  SVG to PNG 

[8]  RAW to JPEG

[9]  ICO to PNG

[10] ICO to JPEG

[11] WebP to PNG 

[12] WebP to JPEG


Select from the above options : """).strip())
    
    except ValueError:

        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
        print("Please try again with a valid input")
        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
        
        return file_type()
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
    
    filetype = None

    global conversion_extension
    global conversion_type
    conversion_extension = None
    conversion_type = None


# 1. JPEG TO PNG
    if user_input == 1 :  
        filetype = "*.jpg;*.jpeg"
        conversion_extension = ".png"
        conversion_type = "PNG"

# 2. PNG TO JPEG
    elif user_input == 2 :
        filetype = "*.png"
        conversion_extension = '.jpg'
        conversion_type = 'JPEG'

# 3. BMP TO GIF
    elif user_input == 3 :
        filetype = "*.bmp"
        conversion_extension = '.gif'
        conversion_type = 'GIF'

# 4. TIFF TO JPEG
    elif user_input == 4 :
        filetype = "*.tiff;*.tif"
        conversion_extension = '.jpg'
        conversion_type = 'JPEG'

# 5. GIF TO PNG
    elif user_input == 5 :
        filetype = "*.gif"
        conversion_extension = '.png'
        conversion_type = 'PNG'

# 6. PSD TO PNG
    elif user_input == 6 :
        filetype = "*.psd"
        conversion_extension = '.png'
        conversion_type = 'PNG'

# 7. SVG TO PNG 
    elif user_input == 7 :
        filetype = "*.svg"
        conversion_extension = '.png'
        conversion_type = 'PNG'

# 8. RAW TO JPEG
    elif user_input == 8 :
        filetype = "*.raw"
        conversion_extension = '.jpg'
        conversion_type = 'JPEG'

# 9. ICO TO PNG 
    elif user_input == 9 :
        filetype = "*.ico"
        conversion_extension = '.png'
        conversion_type = 'PNG'

# 10. ICO TO JPEG
    elif user_input == 10 :
        filetype = "*.ico"
        conversion_extension = '.jpg' 
        conversion_type = 'JPEG'

# 11. WEBP TO PNG
    elif user_input == 11 :
        filetype = "*.webp"
        conversion_extension = '.png'
        conversion_type = 'PNG'
    
# 12. WEBP TO JPEG
    elif user_input == 12 :
        filetype = "*.webp"
        conversion_extension = '.jpg'
        conversion_type = 'JPEG'  

    else:
        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
        print("Please try again with a valid input")
        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
        
        return file_type()


    return filetype


def open_gui_for_individual_file(filetype):

    filetypes = (
        (f"Image Files ({filetype})", filetype),
        ("All Files", '*.*')
    )

    add_more_input = "x"

    files = []


    while add_more_input == "x":

        new_files = list(filedialog.askopenfilenames(
            title="Title",
            initialdir="%USERPROFILE%\Downloads",
            filetypes=filetypes
        ))

        files.extend(new_files)

        global strip_file_name
        strip_file_name = lambda filepath: os.path.split(filepath)[1]

        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')

        for count,file in enumerate(files):
            filename = strip_file_name(file)
            print(f"{count + 1}. {filename}\n\n")

        add_more_input = str(input("\n\nPress \"X\" to add more images or \"Q\" to start conversion : ").strip().lower())
        
        if add_more_input == "q":
            
            if files:           
                print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                print("Starting Conversion")
                print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')

            else:
                print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                print("No Files Were Selected")
                print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                
                exit()
    


        else:
            while add_more_input not in 'xq':
                add_more_input = str(input("\n\nPress \"X\" to add more images or \"Q\" to start conversion : ").strip().lower())
                if add_more_input == "q":
                    
                    if files:
                        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                        print("Starting Conversion")
                        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                    
                    else:

                        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                        print("No Files Were Selected")
                        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------------\n\n')
                        
                        exit()
        
                        

    return files


def open_gui_save_location():
    save_file_to = filedialog.askdirectory(title="Save To")
    return save_file_to


def image_conversion(file):

    output_path = open_gui_save_location()

    for image in file:

        if user_input != 7 :
            with Image.open(image) as img:
                filename = os.path.splitext(strip_file_name(image))[0]
            
                img = img.convert('RGB')
                img.save(f'{output_path}/{filename}{conversion_extension}',conversion_type)
                
        elif user_input == 7:
            filename = os.path.splitext(strip_file_name(image))[0]
            cairosvg.svg2png(url=image,write_to=f'{output_path}/{filename}{conversion_extension}')
        

        


image_conversion(open_gui_for_individual_file(file_type()))
```

I tried to follow some steps mentioned in the documentation related to ImageMath but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: Your example should be *minimal* - that means all the `tkinter` and code for the menu is not relevant. The only part that is relevant is how you loaded the image with PIL and how you saved it. See [mcve].

Comment: please learn about the "alpha channel", which represents transparency. think about how a conversion to JPEG (which does NOT have that) is supposed to work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I understand....I'm new to this stuff so I'm still learning...Will definitely keep that in mind from now on :)

Comment: I wasn't intending to be harsh or critical - it's just that answerers are volunteers who give their time freely and it helps if people post well-researched, concise questions that get to the point quickly and include all necessary but no unnecessary information. Anyway, welcome to SO.

Comment: @MarkSetchell No offense was taken sir. I understand that being vague could cause general confusion and take one's precious time. Thank you for the insight 

Answer (score 1):

Many images are RGB (JPEG images). Some images (PNG, TIFF, GIF) can be RGBA, which means they have an alpha, a.k.a. transparency, channel.

Where the image is transparent, you can see through it, i.e. what is behind it. That also means you cannot see what's in its RGB channels and the creator could have included anything.

If you convert an image with an alpha channel to JPEG (or any format lacking alpha) you need to decide what to do with transparent pixels... some folks make them white, some folks make them black. But if you just discard the alpha channel you will see whatever the creator left in the RGB channels of any transparent pixels.

---

You probably want something like this to paste white wherever the image is transparent:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# Load image
im = Image.open('BxitS.png')

# Check if it contains alpha channel
if 'A' in im.mode:
   # Extract the alpha channel and invert it
   alpha = im.getchannel('A')
   alpha = ImageOps.invert(alpha)
   # Paste white onto image wherever it is transparent
   im.paste((255,255,255), mask=alpha)
   im.convert('RGB').save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

---

Change to `im.paste((127,127,127), mask=alpha)` if you want to paste mid-grey.

[image]

---

As Christoph points out in the comments, it may be more common to paste the image with transparency onto a solid white background, rather than replacing transparent pixels with white ones:

```
from PIL import Image

 # Load image
 im = Image.open('BxitS.png')

 # Check if it contains alpha channel
 if 'A' in im.mode:
   # Create new solid white background image same size
   bg = Image.new('RGB', im.size, 'white')
   # Paste original image onto white background, using its transparency as the mask
   bg.paste(im, mask=im)
   bg.save('result.jpg')
```

Comment: note that this pastes a flat color *on top of* the actual foreground. the math is not equivalent to pasting the foreground onto a flat-color background.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Good point - I added code to paste the other way.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you so much for this solution....the code for both replacing the transparent pixels and adding a solid background work flawlessly :)